# Is it possible to use XCode Build parameters with xcobebuild?

Tags: xcode, xcodebuild

Within XCode, you can edit options such as the Header Search Paths and use build-specific variables such as `$(BUILT_PRODUCTS_DIR)` or `$(SDKROOT)` and the like. Is it possible to use these variables from `xcodebuild` on the command line?

Usage scenario:
For my project, I must use `xcodebuild`, and I have added `HEADER_SEARCH_PATHS="<custom path>"` to account for a missing file from the remotely downloaded project. This appears to have broken the linker (`ld: library not found for -lCrashReporterClient`), so I'd like to restore the default setting for `LIBRARY_SEARCH_PATHS`, which I understand should just be `$(SDKROOT)`.

Answer (score 0):

I know that you are trying to build Chess.app from your question yesterday, so I'm going to go out on a limb and say this question is related.

The error is because the `CrashReporterClient.a` static library Chess.app  does not exist. you have to build/download it and add it to the project.

The good news is, you don't need the crash reporter client library to build (its optional). just go to the build settings for the target and remove that library from the linked libraries list.

**to answer your question, yes you can specify values for build settings on the command line to xcodebuild in the form `setting=value`**

that error is unrelated to the value of `HEADER_SEARCH_PATHS`